# I am facing issue with publishing my ASP.NET Core MVC web app in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am facing issue in publishing ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app, VS 2022.

I get thise error:

> System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'Workspace update handler 12771809' closed because of an exception: Attempted to push a project evaluation that regressed in version..
>
> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: Attempted to push a project evaluation that regressed in version.
>
> at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Handlers.AbstractEvaluationCommandLineHandler.EnqueueProjectEvaluation(IComparable version, IProjectChangeDiff evaluationDifference)

First time I am publishing to Azure, it is code first approach, while running the publish it is showing publish succeeded but then suddenly automatically canceling.

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2022

Comment: Is it 17.8 or 17.9?

Comment: It is Version 17.8.2

Comment: Update it to 17.8.3 or 17.9

Comment: I have one more issue, as i deployed one app through azure devops pipelines the view i is not retrieving, is that also will be related with the version issue?

Comment: Can you run locally once and deploy again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Posting my comments as answer.

> System.AggregateException: Project system data flow 'Workspace update handler 12771809' closed because of an exception: Attempted to push a project evaluation that regressed in version.

- This error is occurring due to the version issue with visual studio.
- Fix for this issue has been merged into 17.8.3 and 17.9 version of Visual Studio. Refer the [article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-Version-1782-Error-pulling-changes/10533645?space=41&sort=newest).
- To resolve this error, you have to [install](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) (or) upgrade visual studio version to 17.8.3 or 17.9.0 version in the Visual Studio Installer.

[image]

- After upgrading the IDE to the latest version, you will be able to deploy the application to Azure.

[image]